# Scrape YouTube descriptions for marketplace URLs

Tags: web-scraping, youtube-api

I am trying to scrape Youtube descriptions to find merchandise marketplace links (i.e. teespring). I cannot find a usable function in the Youtube Data API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All the listed methods are in [Youtube Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) list and there are no mentions of marketplace URL actions.

Comment: Is there a way to scrape the video descriptions themselves though? I am basically just looking for occurrences of certain strings of text.

Comment: Yes, by passing ["snippet"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) as your 'part' property. It contains its title, description, and category.